# Throwing an Exception inside Object Class and catching it outside?

Tags: php, api, exception

What I am trying to do is throw an exception inside the class.

And then be able to catch it outside when executing.

```
class api {

    public function __construct($user_id, $token) {}

    public function post($data) {
        throw new customException\Post('Error 1');
    }

}
```

---

```
try {

    $api = new api('id','key');
    $output = $api->post($data);

} catch(customException\Post $e) {
    var_dump($e);
} catch(exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

How would I get something like this to work?

---

I cannot get `customException\Post` to work like that...why is that?

When I use `customException` I get this error:

```
Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function api::__construct(), 1 passed in /var/www/.../api_2.3.php on line 81 and exactly 2 expected in /var/www/.../api_2.3.php:28
```

Comment: Wheres your custom exception class? Whats not working? Errors?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Posted the error in the question.

Comment: In your code, your passing 2 params to the api class construct, so thats confusing..

Comment: @LawrenceCherone There is no problem with the construct, it's just not relevant to this and I've left it empty (on here).

Comment: Whats `$api = new api('id','key');`? Also are you using an autoloader?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Two strings, provided by the user to authenticate the api. The constructor just adds them to private variables. And they are used when posting using curl. But it's not relevant to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your not using namespaces:

```
<?php
class CustomException_Post extends Exception {}

class api {
    public function __construct($user_id, $token) {}

    public function post($data) {
        throw new CustomException_Post('Error 1');
    }
}

$data = [];
try {
    $api = new api('id','key');
    $output = $api->post($data);
} catch (CustomException_Post $e) {
    var_dump($e);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

https://3v4l.org/Q196X

If you are, then you need an autoloader, presuming your using composer it would look something like this *after adding your psr4 autoloading entry*:

In `CustomException` folder, file called `Post.php`.

```
<?php
namespace CustomException;
class Post extends \Exception {}
```

Then in your code you can use:

```
<?php

use CustomException;

class api {
    public function __construct($user_id, $token) {}

    public function post($data) {
        throw new CustomException\Post('Error 1');
    }
}

$data = [];
try {
    $api = new api('id','key');
    $output = $api->post($data);
} catch (CustomException\Post $e) {
    var_dump($e);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Comment: The `catch (Exception $e)` didn't catch an error that occurred inside the Object Class (I didn't throw it). Do I need to have try and catch in there too?

Comment: What do you mean by Object Class? You can only catch once, so if CustomException got caught then it won't hit the next catch block. If no try catch wraps by the time it gets to the global scope, then its uncaught.

Comment: No, the custom didn't catch. By mistake I was trying to check `is_array()` the array I was checking wasn't correct. So got an uncaught error. How do I catch those too?

Comment: This is the error I get: `Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in` That is not being caught. I know what is causing the error, and making it on purpose. How can I catch this?

Comment: Use [`Throwable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php) https://3v4l.org/3O9Q0 though >= PHP 7, so try to prevent it in your code by not using objects as arrays, well unless you use ArrayObject's https://3v4l.org/PoibB ;p

Comment: If I use `Throwable` do I need the regular `Exception`?

Comment: Upto you, but genrally you shouldnt need to think about catching fatal errors because you should make sure that they dont happen, fatal errors happen because of bad code, like just because you can you wouldn't look into trying to catch a ParseError: https://3v4l.org/206eP